Jmeter ultimate thread group is giving wrong output for total no of samplers
I have below configuration,
└── Ultimate Thread Group
├── Start Threads Count: 10
├── Initial Delay: 0
├── Start Time: 10
├── Hold Load For: 0
├── Shutdown Time: 0
enter image description here
what i am expecting is 1req will hit at every 1 secs but after the whole test it run
the total samplers are becoming 90.
enter image description here

Your expectation is wrong, the HTTP Request sampler will be executed by all virtual users according to the schedule you've provided as fast as it will be possible.
The actual number of sample results will depend on:

the number of threads (virtual users)
your test duration
your system under test response time

If you want to limit JMeter's throughput to 1 request per second you should use a Timer, for example:

Precise Throughput Timer


or Throughput Shaping Timer




Can you explain my configuration pls? do you mean 10 users will hit at every sec?

Look, you have 1 user and 1 second response time, you will have 1 request per second. You have 2 users and 1 second response time - you will have 2 requests per second. You have 2 users and 0.5 seconds response time - you will have 4 request per second. You have 2 users and 2 seconds response time - you will have 1 request per second. In general - more users -> more throughput (as long as the system under test can handle this). More information: What is Throughput in JMeter?

Sorry to ask again, but a normal thread group doesn't work like this and in ultimate thread group, 10 user 10 sec startup time means it should run 1 user per sec, and it is not like this then how can we trust the UI of jmeter(which explains the same)

It means that each 1 second new user is being added, on 1st second you have 1 user, on 2nd second 2 users, by 10th second you will have 10 users, all users will run the HTTP Request as fast as they can (unless you use Timers) All thread groups work the same way, it's a matter of how do you configure them. More information: JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide

here the ultimate thread group is hitting the API as per the response time so what is the use of ultimate thread group where i need to perform  stress testing and i want to be specific with the no of users hitting the API per second, note;- Precise throughput timer will help me only for one row in Ultimate thread group and what if i want the rate to be diff in for diff row,
